# Polygonize problem

Tags: qgis, polygonize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Polygonize function doesn’t overlay the shape file over the raster file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48552/polygonize-function-doesnt-overlay-the-shape-file-over-the-raster-file)

When using "Polygonize" in Quantum GIS, I'm getting a polygon shapefile output that is a mirror picture of the (1-band) raster image.  Where have I done wrong?